# Does "synchronized I/O" always mean "blocking I/O"?

Tags: linux, io, synchronized

I'm just confused about the "synchronized/asynchronized I/O" and "blocking/non-blocking I/O". I suppose that "synchronized I/O" always mean some kind of blocking I/O like read/write, they're blocking operations, so they're "synchronized I/O".

Please kindly help to correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Asynchronous" or "non-blocking" I/O are, indeed, effectively synonymous. However, if we're using Linux terminology, "blocking" and "synchronized" I/O are different.

"Blocking" just tells you that the syscall won't return until the kernel has recorded the data... *somewhere*. There's no guarantee that this record is persistent in the event of an unexpected power loss or hardware failure; it can simply be a writeahead cache, for example -- so your blocking call can return at a point where other processes running at the time can see the write, but where that write would be lost if a power failure took place.

"Synchronized" in the `O_SYNC` sense tells you that the syscall won't return until the data is *actually persisted to hardware*.

---

Thus: All synchronized I/O is blocking, but not all blocking I/O is synchronized.